# Win7 - registry hack domain profile to local profile location

Tags: windows-7, domain, migration, windows-registry, local

With Windows XP, if I wanted to add a user logging in locally on their computer to a domain and keep their local profile, I could change the profile location in the registry for the domain profile to point at the local profile. 
I did this by changing the entry in \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

With Windows 7, if I try the same thing the user logs in with a 'temporary' profile. I have tried changing the permissions of the local users profile folder to give the domain profile full ownership and also added the domain profile as a local admin, still doesnt work.

Does anyone know how to get this to work? Or is there a better way to migrate profiles in Win7 that doesn't involve waiting around while all files are copied from the local profile to the domain profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can acomplish that changint the path using MMC, adding the snaping Local Users and Groups, and changing the profile of the Path.

After that if you get the Temporary Profile error you can fix it starting the computer with an account with addministrative rights.

Open the registry (regedit.exe).
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
Delete the key with the SID of the USER. (This key will generated again after the user starts for the first time)

If you dont know the SID of the user of you are running you can get it starting a command prompt with that user (run as works) and running **whoami /user**